# Is it possible to show on the screen only one row(not a grid) of items inRecycleView with FlexboxLayoutManager

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

If it is possible to define RecycleView with FlexboxLayoutManager to show on the screen only one line(row) instead of grid(two dimensions - row and column)

Comment: I need to fit row of items on the screen according to the size of the screen and with center orientation

Comment: please provide rough ux, it will help us to understand the requirements